# BFS algorithm doesn't end while trying to solve 15 puzzle JAVA

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a solver for 15 puzzle using BFS algorithm in Java. The problem is that when I launch the program it ends in endless loop. I have tried with simple input states, for example swaping only 2 numbers from solved state and it worked. It seems to have difficulty with more complex problems.

I checked everything, if the queues are filled with correct states, if the zero indexes are fine withing the states. It looks like it should work just fine but it doesn't. Here is my code:

Program.java

```
package Puzzle;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Program {

    public static final int[][] solved = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 0 } };
    public static final State solvedState = new State(solved, 4, 4, new Point(3, 3));
    static Solution solution;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if(args.length != 5)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number of arguments in configuration. Given args:");
            int nr = 0;
            for (var arg : args)
            {
                System.out.println(nr++ + ": " + arg);
            }
            return;
        }

        State initialState = ReadInitialStateFromFile(args[2]);

        switch (args[0])
        {
            case "bfs":
                solution = new BFS(initialState, args[1]);
                break;
            case "dfs":
                //solution = new DFS(initialState, args[1]);
                break;
            case "astr":
                //solution = new AStar(initialState, args[1]);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("incorrect method parameter");
                return;
        }

        long starttime = System.nanoTime();
        String solutionString = solution.FindSolution();
        long endtime = System.nanoTime();

        long elapsedTime = endtime - starttime;
        long elapsedTimeMS = elapsedTime/1000000;

        int solutionLength = solutionString != "No solution found!" ? solutionString.length() : -1;

        WriteResultState(args[3], solutionString);
        WriteAdditionalInfo(args[4],
                solutionLength,
                solution.numberOfVisitedStates,
                solution.numberOfProcessedStates,
                solution.maxDepth,
                elapsedTimeMS
        );
    }

    public static State ReadInitialStateFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        String data = null;
        int height = -1;
        int width = -1;
        Point point = new Point();
        int [][] puzzle = null;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        try {
            data = br.readLine();
            if(data == null || data.length() != 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("Dimentions are not correct");
            }
            String[] dimentions = data.split(" ");
            height = Integer.parseInt(dimentions[0]);
            width = Integer.parseInt(dimentions[1]);

            puzzle = new int[width][height];

            for(int i=0; i<width;i++){
                String values[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
                if(values.length != width)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.format("Values in row {0} are not correct", i));
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
                    //System.out.println(value);
                    if(value == 0)
                    {
                        point = new Point(i, j);
                        System.out.println("zero point" + point.toString());
                    }
                    puzzle[i][j] = value;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }

        return new State(puzzle, height, width, point);
    }

    private static void WriteResultState(String resultStatePath, String solution) throws IOException {
        int resultLenght = solution != "No solution found!" ? solution.length() : -1;
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(resultStatePath);
        fw.write(resultLenght);
        if(resultLenght != -1)
            fw.write(solution.toUpperCase());
        fw.close();
    }

    private static void WriteAdditionalInfo(String additionalInfoPath, int resultLength, int numberOfVisitedStates, int numberOfProcessedStates, int maxDepth, long calculationTime) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(additionalInfoPath);
        fw.write(resultLength);
        fw.write(numberOfProcessedStates);
        fw.write(numberOfVisitedStates);
        fw.write(maxDepth);
        fw.write(String.valueOf(calculationTime));
    }

}
```

State.java

```
package Puzzle;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class State {
    public State previousState;
    public List<State> nextStates;
    public int[][] puzzle;
    public char move;
    public String moveSet;
    public static int width, height; 
    public Point zeroIndex;
    public int depth = 0;

    public State(int[][] p, int _height, int _width, Point _zeroIndex) {
        nextStates = new ArrayList<State>();
        puzzle = new int[_height][_width];
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        puzzle = Arrays.copyOf(p, p.length);
        zeroIndex = _zeroIndex;
        moveSet = "";
    }

    public State(State state)
    {
        moveSet = state.moveSet;
        nextStates = new ArrayList<State>();
        puzzle = new int[state.height][state.width];
        previousState = state.previousState;
        for(int i=0; i < state.height;i++){
            for(int j =0; j<state.width; j++)
            {
                this.puzzle[i][j] = state.puzzle[i][j];
            }
        }
        //this.puzzle = Arrays.copyOf(state.puzzle, state.puzzle.length);
        zeroIndex = new Point(state.zeroIndex);

    }

    public State Move(char direction)
    {

        State newState = new State(this);
        newState.move = direction;
        newState.moveSet += direction;
        newState.previousState = this;
        newState.depth = depth + 1;
        switch (direction)
        {
            case 'u':
                int tempu = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];
                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x - 1][zeroIndex.y];
                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x - 1][zeroIndex.y] = tempu;
                newState.zeroIndex.x--;
                break;
            case 'd':
                int tempd = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];

                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x + 1][zeroIndex.y];
                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x + 1][zeroIndex.y] = tempd;
                newState.zeroIndex.x++;
                break;
            case 'l':
                int templ = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];

                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y-1];
                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y-1] = templ;
                newState.zeroIndex.y--;
                break;
            case 'r':
                int tempr = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];

                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y + 1];
                newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y + 1] = tempr;
                newState.zeroIndex.y++;
//                System.out.println(newState.zeroIndex.toString());
//                System.out.println(this.zeroIndex.toString());

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return newState;
    }


    public void GenerateNextStates(String order)
    {
        char [] chars = order.toCharArray();
        for(char direction : chars)
        {
            if(IsMovePossible(direction) == true && IsNotGoingBack(direction) == true)
            {
                this.nextStates.add(this.Move(direction));
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean IsMovePossible(char direction)
    {
        if ((!"udlr".contains(Character.toString(direction))) ||
                (zeroIndex.x == 0 && direction == 'u') ||
                (zeroIndex.x == height - 1 && direction == 'd') ||
                (zeroIndex.y == 0 && direction == 'l') ||
                (zeroIndex.y == width - 1 && direction == 'r'))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Print()
    { for(int i = 0; i < height;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(puzzle[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public boolean IsSolution()
    {
        int correctValue = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < State.height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < State.width; j++)
            {
                if (i == State.height - 1 && j == State.width - 1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (puzzle[i][j] != correctValue++)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean IsPuzzleSame(State other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < State.height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < State.width; j++)
            {
                if(this.puzzle[i][j] != other.puzzle[i][j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean IsNotGoingBack(char direction)
    {
         if((this.move == 'l' && direction == 'r') ||
            (this.move == 'u' && direction == 'd') ||
            (this.move == 'r' && direction == 'l') ||
            (this.move == 'd' && direction == 'u'))
        {
            //System.out.println("znaleziono powrót");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Solution.java

```
package Puzzle;

import java.util.Queue;

public abstract class Solution {

    public static State solutionState;
    public static String neighborhoodSearchOrder;
    public static int numberOfVisitedStates;
    public static int numberOfProcessedStates;
    public static int maxDepth;

    public abstract String FindSolution();

    protected boolean IsPuzzleStateNew(Queue<State> q, State newState)
    {
        for (State state : q)
        {
            if (state.IsPuzzleSame(newState))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

BFS.java

```
package Puzzle;

import java.util.*;

public class BFS extends Solution {

    public BFS(State _initialState, String _neighborhoodSearchOrder)
    {
        this.solutionState = _initialState;
        this.neighborhoodSearchOrder = _neighborhoodSearchOrder.toLowerCase();

    }

    @Override
    public String FindSolution() {
        Queue<State> toVisit = new LinkedList<State>();
        Queue<State> visited = new LinkedList<State>();
        String solutionString = "";
        boolean solutionReady = false;

        toVisit.add(solutionState);

        int z = 0;

        while(toVisit.size() > 0)
        {
//            System.out.println("visited");
//            for(int i=0; i<visited.size();i++){
//                System.out.println("visited size: " + visited.size());
//            }
//
            //System.out.println(toVisit.size());

            State currentState = toVisit.remove();
            visited.add(currentState);
            System.out.println("Numer iteracji: " + z);
            //currentState.Print();

            if(currentState.depth > maxDepth)
            {
                maxDepth = currentState.depth;
            }

            if(currentState.IsSolution())
            {
                solutionString = currentState.moveSet;
                solutionReady = true;
                break;
            }

            currentState.GenerateNextStates(neighborhoodSearchOrder);


            Queue<State> allStates = new LinkedList<State>();
            allStates.addAll(toVisit);
            allStates.addAll(visited);

//            for (State state: currentState.nextStates){
//                System.out.println(state.zeroIndex.toString());
//                state.Print();
//            }
            for (State state : currentState.nextStates)
            {
                if(IsPuzzleStateNew(allStates, state))
                {
                    toVisit.add(state);
                }
            }
            allStates.clear();
            z++;
        }
        numberOfVisitedStates = visited.size() + toVisit.size();
        numberOfProcessedStates = visited.size();
        System.out.println(numberOfVisitedStates);
        System.out.println(numberOfProcessedStates);
        return solutionReady ? solutionString : "No solutionString found";
    }
}
```

I have spent so much time troubleshooting this and I am honestly hopeless right now. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not taking forever based on the sheer size/config of the puzzle?  Looking at your code I get 2x2 solved `4 attempts Solution rd` (although you have to force this one), 3x3 solved in `137932 attempts Solution: drrullddruurdllurrdldr` out of a possible ~300k options.  4x4 looks like it has ~2^13 possible options, so it'll take a while if unlucky (which is still running).

Comment: Maybe that's the case. But i feel like the bfs should work faster, based on what my collage is telling me. They clearly told me to use bfs to solve 4x4 puzzle so i guess it should not take several hours to solve one.

Comment: Can you look at? Getting rid of some of your extra loops by using a `Set<> visited` instead of Queue?  Can you prioritize the `Queue<> toVisit` so that some next moves take priority over others?

Comment: Take into consideration the 4x4 puzzle has 16!/2 = 1.0461395e+13 different states. A 3x3 puzzle has only 9!/2 = 181440 different states. Did you check your program on 3x3 ? For more help make your code [mre] by hard-coding test data, to remove dependency on an unavailable file.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code on 4x4 puzzles. It solved correctly puzzles requiring up to 14 steps, but took a long time.
I stopped a 15 steps puzzle solve run after 19 hours.

To speed the code up I introduced a `hashCode()` method in `State`.
Implementing `hashCode()` allowed me to change the costly `if(IsPuzzleStateNew(allStates, state))` test by using a `Set` for 
`visited` and made `isPuzzleStateNew` and `isPuzzleSame` redundant.
I also refactored `isSolution` to make it more generic and faster.

Times changed dramatically and puzzles up to 16 steps run witn no issues:

- 11 steps puzzle went down from 13 seconds to 0.2 sec
- 12 steps puzzle went down from 56 seconds to 0.2
- 13 steps puzzle went down from 100 seconds to 0.2
- 14 steps puzzle went down from 340 seconds to 0.4
- 15 steps puzzle stopped after 19 hours 0.6
- 16 steps puzzle takes 1.2

Testing puzzles which require 35 and 80 steps crash, from reasons that still needs to be investigated.

The following in an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as you are expected to post when asking or answering (you can copy-paste the wntire code into `Program.java` and run):

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class Program {

    public static int[][] solve, solved;
    public static State solvedState, initialState;
    static Solution solution;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        solved = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 0 } };
        solvedState = new State(solved);

        //run various tests (consider writing a JUnit test)
        int[] testcases = {1, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 35, 80};

        for(int test : testcases) {
            System.out.println("########## "+test+" ##########");
            testCase(test);

            solution = new BFS(initialState, solvedState, "udlr");

            long starttime = System.nanoTime();
            String solutionString = solution.findSolution();
            long elapsedTimeMS = (System.nanoTime() - starttime)/1000000;

            if(test != solutionString.length()) {
                System.err.println("Test "+ test + " wrong length "+ solutionString.length() );
            }
            int solutionLength = solutionString != "No solution found!" ? solutionString.length() : -1;

            WriteResultState(solutionString);
            WriteAdditionalInfo(
                    solutionLength,
                    solution.getNumberOfVisitedStates(),
                    solution.getNumberOfProcessedStates(),
                    solution.getMaxDepth(),
                    elapsedTimeMS
                    );
        }
    }

    private static void testCase(int numberOfTestCase){

        switch (numberOfTestCase){

        case 1:
            solve =  new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 0, 15 } };
            break;
        default: case 4: //4 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 10, 11, 12 }, { 9, 13, 14, 15 } };
            break;
        case 10: // 10 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 3, 4, 8 }, { 6, 2, 7, 0 }, { 5, 10, 11, 12 }, { 9, 13, 14, 15 } };
            break;
        case 11:// 11 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 3, 4, 8 }, { 6, 2, 0, 7 }, { 5, 10, 11, 12 }, { 9, 13, 14, 15 } };
            break;
        case 12:// 12 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 3, 4, 8 }, { 6, 0, 2, 7 }, { 5, 10, 11, 12 }, { 9, 13, 14, 15 } };
            break;
        case 13:// 13 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 3, 4, 8 }, { 6, 10, 2, 7 }, { 5, 0, 11, 12 }, { 9, 13, 14, 15 } };
            break;
        case 14:// 14 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 5, 1, 2, 4 }, { 6, 10, 3, 7 }, { 0, 14, 12, 8 }, { 9, 13, 11, 15 } };
            //solve = new int[][] { { 1, 7, 2, 4},{ 9, 5, 3, 0},{ 6, 10, 12, 8},{ 13, 14, 11, 15} };
            break;
        case 15: // 15 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 7, 2, 0},{ 9, 5, 3, 4},{ 6, 10, 12, 8},{ 13, 14, 11, 15} };
            break;

        case 16:// 16 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 0, 2, 11, 3 }, { 1, 6, 7, 4 }, { 5, 9, 12, 8 }, { 13, 10, 14, 15 } };
            break;
        case 35:// 35 steps to solve
            solve = new int[][] { { 1, 10, 15, 4 }, { 13, 6, 3, 8 }, { 2, 9, 12, 7 }, { 14, 5, 0, 11 } };
            break;
        case 80:// 80 steps to solve. max possible steps for 15 puzzle
            solve = new int[][] { { 0, 12, 9, 13 }, { 15, 11, 10, 14 }, { 3, 7, 2, 5 }, { 4, 8, 6, 1 } };
            break;
        }

        initialState = new State(solve);
    }

    private static void WriteResultState(/*String resultStatePath,*/ String solution) throws IOException {

        int resultLenght = solution != "No solution found!" ? solution.length() : -1;
        System.out.println("solution length: "+resultLenght);
        if(resultLenght != -1) {
            System.out.println(solution.toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    private static void WriteAdditionalInfo(/*String additionalInfoPath,*/int resultLength, int numberOfVisitedStates,
            int numberOfProcessedStates, int maxDepth, long calculationTime) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Length:  "+resultLength);
        System.out.println("Processed states: "+numberOfProcessedStates);
        System.out.println("Visited states  : "+ numberOfVisitedStates);
        System.out.println("Depth: "+maxDepth);
        System.out.println("Time: "+String.valueOf(calculationTime));
    }
}

class State {

    //use private fields. access with getters / setters
    private State previousState;
    private final List<State> nextStates;
    private final int[][] puzzle;
    private char move;
    private String moveSet;
    private final int width, height; //should not be static
    private final Point zeroIndex;
    private  int depth = 0;

    public State(int[][] puzzle) {
        nextStates = new ArrayList<>();
        this.puzzle = puzzle;
        width = puzzle[0].length;
        height = puzzle.length;
        zeroIndex = get0Location();
        if(zeroIndex == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No 0 is puzzle");
        moveSet = "";
    }

    public State(int[][] puzzle, int height, int width, Point zeroIndex) {
        nextStates = new ArrayList<>();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.puzzle = puzzle;
        this.zeroIndex = zeroIndex;
        moveSet = "";
    }

    public State(State state)
    {
        moveSet = state.moveSet;
        nextStates = new ArrayList<>();
        width = state.width;
        height = state.height;
        puzzle = new int[state.height][state.width];
        previousState = state.previousState;
        for(int i=0; i < state.height;i++){
            puzzle[i] = Arrays.copyOf(state.puzzle[i], state.puzzle[i].length);
        }
        zeroIndex = new Point(state.zeroIndex);
    }

    public State move(char direction)
    {

        State newState = new State(this);
        newState.move = direction;
        newState.moveSet += direction;
        newState.previousState = this;
        newState.depth = depth + 1;
        switch (direction)
        {
        case 'u':
            int tempu = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x - 1][zeroIndex.y];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x - 1][zeroIndex.y] = tempu;
            newState.zeroIndex.x--;
            break;
        case 'd':
            int tempd = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x + 1][zeroIndex.y];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x + 1][zeroIndex.y] = tempd;
            newState.zeroIndex.x++;
            break;
        case 'l':
            int templ = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y-1];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y-1] = templ;
            newState.zeroIndex.y--;
            break;
        case 'r':
            int tempr = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y] = newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y + 1];
            newState.puzzle[zeroIndex.x][zeroIndex.y + 1] = tempr;
            newState.zeroIndex.y++;
            break;
        }

        return newState;
    }

    public void generateNextStates(String order)
    {
        char [] chars = order.toCharArray();
        for(char direction : chars)
        {
            if(isMovePossible(direction) == true && isNotGoingBack(direction) == true)
            {
                nextStates.add(this.move(direction));
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isMovePossible(char direction)
    {
        if (!"udlr".contains(Character.toString(direction)) ||
                zeroIndex.x == 0 && direction == 'u' ||
                zeroIndex.x == height - 1 && direction == 'd' ||
                zeroIndex.y == 0 && direction == 'l' ||
                zeroIndex.y == width - 1 && direction == 'r')
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < height;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                sb.append(String.format("%1$4s", puzzle[i][j]));
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private boolean isNotGoingBack(char direction)
    {
        if(move == 'l' && direction == 'r' ||
                move == 'u' && direction == 'd' ||
                move == 'r' && direction == 'l' ||
                move == 'd' && direction == 'u')
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private Point get0Location() {
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < width ; col++){
                if (puzzle[row][col] == 0) return new Point(row, col);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    List<State> getNextStates() {
        return nextStates;
    }

    String getMoveSet() {
        return moveSet;
    }

    int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    int[][] getPuzzle(){
        return puzzle;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int[] row : puzzle) {
            for(int i : row) {
                sb.append(i);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString().hashCode();
    }
}

abstract class Solution {

    protected State initialState, solutionState;
    protected String neighborhoodSearchOrder;
    protected int numberOfVisitedStates;
    protected int numberOfProcessedStates;
    protected int maxDepth;

    public abstract String findSolution();

    protected boolean isSolution(State state)
    {
        return Arrays.deepEquals(state.getPuzzle(), solutionState.getPuzzle());
    }

    public int getNumberOfVisitedStates() {
        return numberOfVisitedStates;
    }

    public int getNumberOfProcessedStates() {
        return numberOfProcessedStates;
    }

    public int getMaxDepth() {
        return maxDepth;
    }
}

class BFS extends Solution {

    private State currentState;

    private long starttime ;

    public BFS(State initialState,State solutionState, String neighborhoodSearchOrder)
    {
        this.initialState = initialState;
        this.solutionState = solutionState;
        this.neighborhoodSearchOrder = neighborhoodSearchOrder.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String findSolution() {

        starttime = System.nanoTime();
        Queue<State> toVisit = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<State> visited = new HashSet<>();

        String solutionString = "";
        boolean solutionReady = false;
        numberOfVisitedStates = 0;
        numberOfProcessedStates = 0;
        maxDepth = 0;

        toVisit.add(initialState);
        visited.add(initialState);

        while(toVisit.size() > 0)
        {
            currentState = toVisit.remove();
            numberOfProcessedStates++;

            if(currentState.getDepth() > maxDepth)
            {
                maxDepth = currentState.getDepth();
                System.out.println("Processed: "+ numberOfProcessedStates +" nodes, depth: " + maxDepth+ " in "
                        +  (System.nanoTime() - starttime)/1000000000 + " seconds " );
            }

            if(isSolution(currentState))
            {
                solutionString = currentState.getMoveSet();
                solutionReady = true;
                break;
            }

            currentState.generateNextStates(neighborhoodSearchOrder);

            for (State state : currentState.getNextStates())
            {
                if( visited.add(state))
                {
                    toVisit.add(state);
                }
            }
        }

        numberOfVisitedStates = numberOfProcessedStates+ toVisit.size();
        //System.out.println("End state: "+ "\n" + currentState);
        return solutionReady ? solutionString : "No solutionString found";
    }
}
```

For further improvement I would recommend: 
-Check for [solvability](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-instance-15-puzzle-solvable/) before attempting to solve.
-Check if `visited` is needed at all.

Side note: Please see [Java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).